# 2 questions for Spreadsheet script clear cell if another cell is blank & skip the code on a specific sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Script I found and change a little for my needs at the bottom

Question 1
When the agent type a number in the specific col the date & time appear beside
However when they delete the number in the cell the date & time beside stay in the cell.
I want to clear the date & time if the agent clear the number
The script below add the date & time in col "J" if they type (or select) the number in col "I"

Question 2 (For the same function)
In Excel I can add the script in the specific sheet, however in this Google spreadsheet I cannot
My issue is I dont want the script to work on a specific sheets (named: "Report"). How can I do this?
Thanks in advance for your answers

I have this script:

```
   function onEdit() {

   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 9 ) { //checks the column
   var row = r.getRow();
   var time = new Date();
   time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-05:00", "yyyy-MM-dd, hh:mm:ss");
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J' +    row.toString()).setValue(time);
   };

   };
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve both requirements:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var reportSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Report").getName();
  var check = s.getName();
  if (check != reportSheet) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 9 ) { //checks the column
      var row = r.getRow();
      var time = new Date();
      time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-05:00", "yyyy-MM-dd, hh:mm:ss");
      if (r.getValue() != "") {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J' +    row.toString()).setValue(time);
      } else {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J' +    row.toString()).setValue("");
      }
    };
  };
};
```

Note that based on your code you have to type/clear cells individually, you can't use this on multiple cells.